# Web API on Mono constantly getting 404

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache, asp.net-web-api, mono

I'm currently attempting to run a very simple / basic Web API program on OpenSUSE using mod_mono and apache.

The code executes perfectly on my windows machine when running from visual studio, however once deployed to my OpenSUSE box I get nothing but 404 errors trying to trace down the routes.

I'm sure I'm deploying to the correct directory because the .css file that is auto-generated when creating the solution is on the web server and I can see it when I put in the path.

However, I don't see the Web API splash page when I navigate to the website root in a browser, nor do I see the same XML dump when I type in the path /api/Locations on my Linux server as when I do so in my windows / Visual Studio environment.

I'm assuming I need to do something to make Apache respect my routes file, but I'm simply unsure of what this may be. I also am thinking I may need to adjust how my publish is done (I am currently doing this via FTP right through Visual studio).

I don't even know what I don't know at this point, and would love some help on where to look next. Scouring the web has produced a lot of very old / outdated results that seem to be useless.

Comment: I now have WebAPI working perfectly on OpenSUSE with Mono.

A few things to note, case sensitivity of web.config, and other files, including the site style css became an issue. Also I had to do a full rebuild of xsp4 as the build that comes from yast by default is very broken. From there it's important to ensure you properly set up virtual directories in apache so they point to your web api project, I couldn't actually get it working until the virtual directory was set up, and also xsp4 was set as the server to run (xsp2 is default and will only run up to .Net v2) Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your are right. The mono official doc does not make webapi work. It just could make the asp.net aspx web app work.

For the webapi 2.0, I've edited the httpd.conf to commented the AddHandler line which is mono official doc suggested. And then, I added below part next to the AddHandler line:

```
MonoAutoApplication disabled
#AddHandler mono .aspx .ascx .asax .ashx .config .cs .asmx .axd
MonoApplications "/:/var/www/html"
MonoServerPath /usr.bin.mod-mono-server4

    <Location "/">
            Allow from all
            Order allow,deny
            SetHandler mono
    </Location>
```

In this way, my localhost/api/my works fine.

Thank you and https://www.oxfordcc.co.uk/blog/aspnet-web-api-on-linux-apache-with-mono

And I have to say the mono official doc is very basic and not up to date.